# Spring combine with hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-orm

I meet a problem,When I use hibernate without Spring,I always write follow configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

this bind the seesion to thread.But When I use hibernate togther with Spring,I don't know how to implement same configuration,I also write it in applicationContext.xml,but it doesn't work.
throw exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to
>   thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional
>   one here

Actually I just want to bind session to thread,then I can use sessionfactory's getcurrentSession method,Did someone meet the same problem as me,how to solve it.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `@Transactional` annotation on your method which use the hibernate session.

It seems that your methods need transaction.

---

There are lots of way to configure to use transaction in Spring.

Below is the one of them.

Just a snippet so you should use this code in your way.

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

See [SpringMVC 3.2 hibernate docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) for more information.

Comment: Cool!but I am a little confused,according to your configuration and doc of spring,it seems that spring doesn't support to bind session to thread,really?It's a little mess when combined spring with other framework